# Limit to the data passed in a Bundle

Tags: android

Passing values from one activity to another using Bundle.
In some cases , incorrect values are being returned during the retrieval process in another Activity using Bundle.

e.g: In Activity1 , suppose the data put in a bundle as follows:
{value=1 ,  isPrint = false , .........}

In Activity2 , the Bundle displays the following data:

{isPrint=1 , value=null , ......   }

Is there any size limit to the data transferred using Bundle from one Activity to another Activity ?

Any hints/suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any size limit to the data transferred using Bundle from one Activity to another Activity ?

I am not aware of a hard limit, but please keep it well under 1MB. Bundles tend to be copied between processes; the bigger the bundle, the slower that operation is.

> e.g: In Activity1 , suppose the data put in a bundle as follows: {value=1 , isPrint = false , .........}
>   In Activity2 , the Bundle displays the following data:
>   {isPrint=1 , value=null , ...... }

If you are putting `isPrint` into the `Bundle` as a boolean, please retrieve it as a `boolean`, not as an `int`, by using the proper getter. If you are putting `value` into the `Bundle` as an `int`, please retrieve it as an `int`, not as something that could be `null`, by using the proper getter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am retrieving the Bundle values as per the datatypes . I actually passed two different Parcelable arrayLists between two Activity(s), when I faced this problem of corrupted valus.